# SRTM 1arc second bulk download

Tags: srtm

This has been asked before, I am aware, but the web links seem to all be obsolete.
Using EarthExplorer, I can get the dataset and I can download... each tile individually.

I do not want to get any kind of nice ui and fancy search options, but really just the raw data set for further processing, so if there exist a direct link to bulk download the latest version, I would be very interested.

Comment: Please provide a link to when this has been asked before.

Comment: Let us pretend it has not been asked before then. I was seeking far and wide previously and saw the question asked and answers given with outdated links.